# How to implement Twitter Digits Authentication with Azure AD Auth for Asp.net WebApi

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, twitter-digits

I have ASP.Net Web API and I want to authenticate my API using `Twitter Digits Auth` and later will pass that `Digits token` to Azure Active Directory Auth Service.

I got an idea about `Twitter Digits Auth` but I'm confused how can I pass `Digits token` ahead to Azure Active Directory Auth Service.

Please see this diagram which I'm thinking to implement.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `Azure Active Directory Auth Service` mean **Azure App Service Authentication and Authorization**. If I understand correctly, this scenario will not work.

The Azure App Service Authentication and Authorization supports two kinds of authentication flow, client-flow and server-flow. The scenario you mentioned is client-flow which acquire the token from identity data provider first and then exchange the access token with Azure AD using that token. However in this scenario, we need to using the token issued from the identity data provider(Azure Active Directory, facebook, google, microsoftaccount, or twitter.) directly.

If I understand correctly, the **Digits token** is issued from [Digits](https://get.digits.com/) which the Twitter supports. This token is not supported for the Azure App Service Authentication and Authorization. You need to check whether the Twitter support to exchange this token for the token issued from Twitter.

More detail about the client-flow you can refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#a-nameauthenticationaauthenticate-users).

Comment: great thanks in that case I do not want to use Azure AD I simply implement Oauth 2.0 any link for the same ?

Comment: You can check [this document](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth) about OAuth of Twitter.

Comment: thanks but this is difference i think , i'm looking for Digits token integration with my WebAPI